# Trying to convert a hex list from binascii to text

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex

I have been trying to convert this list:

```
[54, 57, 54, 100, 55, 48, 54, 102, 55, 50, 55, 52, 50, 48, 54, 102, 55, 51, 48, 100, 48, 97, 54, 54, 54, 57, 54, 99, 54, 53, 50, 48, 51, 100, 50, 48, 54, 102, 55, 48, 54, 53, 54, 101, 50, 56, 50, 55, 55, 52, 54, 53, 55, 51, 55, 52, 50, 101, 55, 48, 55, 57, 50, 55, 50, 99, 50, 48, 50, 50, 55, 50, 54, 50, 50, 98, 50, 50, 50, 57, 48, 100, 48, 97, 55, 48, 55, 50, 54, 57, 54, 101, 55, 52, 50, 56, 54, 54, 54, 57, 54, 99, 54, 53, 50, 57, 48, 100, 48, 97, 54, 54, 54, 57, 54, 99, 54, 53, 50, 101, 55, 51, 54, 53, 54, 53, 54, 98, 50, 56, 51, 48, 50, 57, 48, 100, 48, 97, 55, 51, 55, 52, 54, 49, 55, 50, 55, 52, 52, 50, 55, 57, 55, 52, 54, 53, 50, 48, 51, 100, 50, 48, 51, 48, 48, 100, 48, 97, 54, 53, 54, 101, 54, 52, 52, 50, 55, 57, 55, 52, 54, 53, 50, 48, 51, 100, 50, 48, 51, 52, 51, 51, 51, 48, 48, 100, 48, 97, 54, 50, 55, 57, 55, 52, 54, 53, 55, 51, 50, 48, 51, 100, 50, 48, 50, 50, 50, 50, 48, 100, 48, 97, 54, 50, 54, 57, 54, 101, 52, 50, 55, 57, 55, 52, 54, 53, 50, 48, 51, 100, 50, 48, 50, 50, 50, 50, 48, 100, 48, 97, 55, 55, 54, 56, 54, 57, 54, 99, 54, 53, 50, 48, 55, 51, 55, 52, 54, 49, 55, 50, 55, 52, 52, 50, 55, 57, 55, 52, 54, 53, 50, 48, 50, 49, 51, 100, 50, 48, 54, 53, 54, 101, 54, 52, 52, 50, 55, 57, 55, 52, 54, 53, 51, 97, 48, 100, 48, 97, 50, 48, 50, 48, 50, 48, 50, 48, 54, 50, 55, 57, 55, 52, 54, 53, 53, 52, 54, 102, 52, 49, 54, 52, 54, 52, 50, 48, 51, 100, 50, 48, 55, 51, 55, 52, 55, 50, 50, 56, 54, 54, 54, 57, 54, 99, 54, 53, 50, 101, 55, 50, 54, 53, 54, 49, 54, 52, 50, 56, 55, 51, 55, 52, 54, 49, 55, 50, 55, 52, 52, 50, 55, 57, 55, 52, 54, 53, 50, 57, 50, 57, 48, 100, 48, 97, 50, 48, 50, 48, 50, 48, 50, 48, 54, 50, 55, 57, 55, 52, 54, 53, 53, 52, 54, 102, 52, 49, 54, 52, 54, 52, 50, 48, 51, 100, 50, 48, 54, 50, 55, 57, 55, 52, 54, 164, 53, 52, 54, 102, 52, 49, 54, 52, 54, 52, 50, 101, 55, 50, 54, 53, 55, 48, 54, 99, 54, 49, 54, 51, 54, 53, 50, 56, 50, 50, 54, 50, 50, 55, 50, 50, 50, 99, 50, 48, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 57, 48, 100, 48, 97, 50, 48, 50, 48, 50, 48, 50, 48, 54, 50, 55, 57, 55, 52, 54, 53, 53, 52, 54, 102, 52, 49, 54, 52, 54, 52, 50, 48, 51, 100, 50, 48, 54, 50, 55, 57, 55, 52, 54, 53, 53, 52, 54, 102, 52, 49, 54, 52, 54, 52, 50, 101, 55, 34, 54, 53, 55, 48, 54, 99, 54, 49, 54, 51, 54, 53, 50, 56, 50, 50, 50, 55, 50, 50, 50, 99, 50, 48, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 57, 48, 100, 48, 97, 50, 48, 50, 48, 50, 48, 50, 48, 54, 50, 55, 57, 55, 52, 54, 53, 53, 52, 54, 102, 52, 49, 54, 52, 54, 52, 50, 48, 51, 100, 50, 48, 54, 50, 55, 57, 55, 52, 54, 53, 53, 52, 54, 102, 52, 49, 54, 52, 54, 52, 50, 101, 55, 50, 54, 53, 55, 48, 54, 99, 54, 49, 54, 51, 54, 53, 50, 56, 50, 55, 54, 50, 50, 50, 50, 55, 50, 99, 50, 48, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 57, 48, 214, 48, 97, 50, 48, 50, 48, 50, 48, 50, 48, 54, 50, 55, 57, 55, 52, 54, 53, 53, 52, 54, 102, 52, 49, 54, 52, 54, 52, 50, 48, 51, 100, 236, 48, 54, 50, 55, 57, 55, 52, 54, 53, 53, 52, 54, 102, 52, 49, 54, 52, 54, 52, 50, 101, 55, 50, 54, 53, 55, 48, 54, 99, 54, 49, 54, 51, 54, 53, 50, 56, 50, 55, 50, 50, 50, 55, 50, 99, 50, 48, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 57, 48, 100, 48, 97, 50, 48, 50, 48, 50, 48, 50, 48, 54, 50, 55, 57, 55, 52, 54, 53, 55, 51, 50, 48, 51, 100, 50, 48, 55, 51, 55, 52, 55, 50, 50, 56, 54, 50, 55, 57, 55, 52, 199, 53, 55, 51, 50, 57, 50, 48, 50, 98, 50, 48, 50, 50, 50, 48, 50, 50, 50, 48, 50, 98, 50, 48, 54, 50, 55, 57, 55, 52, 54, 53, 53, 52, 54, 102, 52, 49, 54, 52, 25, 52, 48, 100, 48, 97, 50, 48, 50, 48, 50, 48, 50, 48, 55, 51, 55, 52, 54, 49, 55, 50, 55, 52, 52, 50, 55, 57, 55, 52, 167, 53, 50, 48, 50, 98, 51, 100, 50, 48, 51, 49, 48, 100, 48, 32, 54, 50, 54, 57, 54, 101, 52, 50, 55, 57, 55, 52, 54, 53, 50, 48, 51, 100, 50, 48, 50, 55, 50, 48, 50, 55, 50, 101, 54, 97, 54, 102, 54, 57, 54, 101, 50, 56, 54, 54, 54, 102, 55, 50, 54, 100, 54, 49, 55, 52, 50, 56, 54, 102, 55, 50, 54, 52, 50, 56, 55, 56, 50, 57, 50, 99, 50, 48, 50, 55, 54, 50, 50, 55, 50, 57, 50, 48, 54, 54, 54, 102, 55, 50, 50, 48, 55, 56, 50, 48, 54, 57, 54, 101, 50, 48, 54, 58, 55, 57, 55, 52, 54, 53, 55, 51, 50, 57, 48, 100, 48, 97, 55, 48, 55, 50, 54, 57, 54, 101, 55, 52, 50, 56, 54, 50, 55, 57, 55, 52, 54, 53, 55, 51, 50, 57, 50, 48, 48, 100, 48, 97, 55, 48, 55, 50, 54, 57, 54, 101, 55, 52, 50, 56, 54, 50, 54, 57, 54, 101, 52, 50, 55, 57, 55, 52, 54, 92, 50, 57]
```

into text
But I can't the only hex I can convert is this:

```
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
```

Comment: what do you mean by a "hex list"? You have a list of `int` objects. What do those integers represent? What would `[54, 57, 54, 100, 55, 48, 54, 102]`, for example, produce? And why?

Comment: what's the value of string you are expecting ?

Comment: I don't know what those integers represent but they should be byte numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to perform yet another conversion: each pair of characters that you got seems to represent an ascii code (again) in hex encoding. If you do that second conversion you'll get a text that is a piece of Python code, except that there seem to be a few out-of-range numbers in the list you provided. But I have left the list as it is. The code below will produce a "█" character every time the value in the list does not represent a hexadecimal character:

```
lst = [] #  your list comes here

def conv(a):
    try:
        return chr(int(a, 16))
    except ValueError:
        return "█"

result = "".join([conv(chr(lst[i])+chr(lst[i+1])) 
            for i in range(0, len(lst), 2)])
import re
# Make sure to never print \r without \n
print(re.sub(r"\r(?!\n)", r"\r\n", result))
```

The output is:

```
import os
file = open('test.py', "rb+")
print(file)
file.seek(0)
startByte = 0
endByte = 430
bytes = ""
binByte = ""
while startByte != endByte:
    byteToAdd = str(file.read(startByte))
    byteToAdd = byt█ToAdd.replace("b'", "")
    byteToAdd = byteToAdd.█eplace("'", "")
    byteToAdd = byteToAdd.replace('b"', "")█
    byteToAdd =█byteToAdd.replace('"', "")
    bytes = str(byt█s) + " " + byteToAd█
    startByt█ += 1
binByte = ' '.join(format(ord(x), 'b') for x in █ytes)
print(bytes) 
print(binByt█)
```

As you can see there is about 1% of the text that has a bad corresponding value in the input list.

Here is another version that includes a mapping for the few entries in your list that are out of range for this conversion to work:

```
lst = [] #  your list comes here

fix = {
    164: 53,
    167: 54,
    34: 50,
    214: 54,
    236: 50,
    199: 54,
    25: 54,
    32: 97,
    58: 50,
    92: 53
}

def conv(a):
    return chr(fix[a] if a in fix else a)

result = "".join([chr(int(conv(lst[i])+conv(lst[i+1]), 16)) 
            for i in range(0, len(lst), 2)])
print(result)
```

The output is:

```
import os
file = open('test.py', "rb+")
print(file)
file.seek(0)
startByte = 0
endByte = 430
bytes = ""
binByte = ""
while startByte != endByte:
    byteToAdd = str(file.read(startByte))
    byteToAdd = byteToAdd.replace("b'", "")
    byteToAdd = byteToAdd.replace("'", "")
    byteToAdd = byteToAdd.replace('b"', "")
    byteToAdd = byteToAdd.replace('"', "")
    bytes = str(bytes) + " " + byteToAdd
    startByte += 1
binByte = ' '.join(format(ord(x), 'b') for x in bytes)
print(bytes) 
print(binByte)
```

Comment: But when I try to do other characters it does not work, any way to use all of the characters in the utf-8 encoding @trincot

Comment: That is quite vague. What information do you have -- why do you mention utf-8? Is there some more info you could share?

Comment: I'm trying to make a corruption engine and some values are bigger than base 16 can handle

Comment: Well, yes, that is what I already said in my answer: some values do not correspond to hex characters. It is like 1% that is wrong. But from the other 99% it is clear that this approach is the right one. I cannot help that your input has 1% errors. You could replace any value that is out of range by a default, then at least you will see text come out that is 99% correct.

Comment: I updated the start of my answer to use a "*" replacement character whenever there is a value in the list that is out of range.

Comment: I'm already working on a new system to decode this, I'll still mark this as resolved for the next person who comes here